# Include js library in Jinja with css

Tags: flask, jinja2

I want to create an html template for a quilljs, a wysiwyg editor. However it requires some js and css files to work. I tried to use block like this:

`main.html`

```html
<head>
    {# some csss import #}
    {% block head %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {# some html #}
    {% include 'quill.html' %}
</body>
```

`quill.html`

```html
{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{{url_for("static", filename="css/quill.snow.css") }}' rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}

{# Some html template for quill #}
```

However it does not work. Is there a way to have a template that add js and css inside the header with jinja ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `include` tag will insert the target template to the current location, while your intention is to inject code to the `<head>` section. I would suggest switching your logic to a different design:

a skeleton.html template where you define all the customizable sections of your html body:

```
<head>
{% block head %}
{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

the template that will be including the sections you want to inject in your skeleton.html, lets call it quill.html here:

```
{% extends "skeleton.html" %}

{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{{url_for("static", filename="css/quill.snow.css") }}' rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<p> this is the quill page</p>
{% endblock %}
```

from your flask route you will be rendering the quill.html.

Comment: I see. So it's better to redefine a base template with quill imports and then include the quill template wherever I want inside a template that use this base.

Comment: i think so, at least thats how i prefer to do things - have a base template with all static content hardcoded there and then with blocks override the page specific stuff.